# Limit size of HTML5 Facebook comment box

Tags: html, css, facebook

I'm trying to limit the vertical height of the Facebook comments from the code generated below but I don't know how to limit the vertical height of the comment box. (for width, the data-width parameter is provided by facebook). Does anyone know how I could do this?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="example.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="500">    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately FB doesn't currently allow the IFRAME method, only the HTML5 and XFBML, so the solution I've used to get around this is to wrap the  tag with another div with "overflow-y" set to scroll, like:

```
<div id="fb_comments">
    <fb:comments href="http://example.com/" num_posts="10" width="500"></fb:comments>
</div>
```

My styling for fb_comments is:

```
#fb_comments { height:400px; padding-bottom:20px; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Comment: But how about mobile. data-mobile="true"

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set the height directly, if you want it to scroll you might want to put it inside an IFrame (Code can be found at developers.facebook.com, just select IFRAME instead of HTML5)

Otherwise you may change the data-num-posts to a lower, or higher value, to make it smaller or larger.