# facebook comment plugin height

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, facebook-comments

I am using `Facebook comments` plugin on my page but the problem is why it is taking entire browser height. I have placed an image which should appear below the comment box but the image is sitting at the bottom of the page since the comment box is occupying the whole browser.

How to restrict tat height??

This is the code I am using.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Facebook Plugin Sample - Facebook Comments </title>
        <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-mobile="true"></div>
        <img src="http://cdn3.1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/toolbox-icon.jpg" style="border:1px #000 solid;" alt="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is how it is showing now

[image]

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxsrp/)**

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any styling on the page besides the border on the image?

Try looking at it with your development tool for your browser, like Firebug for Firefox and see the styling of the plugin and of your image.

You could try wrapping the plugin in a div and styling the height of that div:

```
<head>
  <style>
    #comments_wrapper {
      height: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="comments_wrapper">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-mobile="true"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Your fiddle didn't display amything. I forked it and it seems to be working, though I don't have any comments to show. Here's the fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/CodeWaggle/JHzjG/

Another approach is to add this style:

```
#fb_comments { height:400px; padding-bottom:20px; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

I found it in this answer: [Limit size of HTML5 Facebook comment box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8390061/751619)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ya I had given border to the same class. Even your height solution doesnt work. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/K3CBU/

Comment: You don't see the image in my fiddle? I just saw a solution to style the `fb-comments` div, I'll add it to my answer so you can try it.

Comment: Ya that solution works well for desktop mode of comments but when I add mobile version it is not working well. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/JHzjG/2/